# How to make a simultaneous call to api?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have an async function that calls my API simultaneously, but Promise.all() resolving after about 2 seconds for me (One request resolving in about 200ms). That means my requests resolving one after another, not simultaneously even if they started asyncronious.

```
// don't run in client side of browser - CORS
    async asyncData () {
      axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        console.log('Start: ', new Date)
        return config
      })
      const promise1 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
      const promise2 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      const promise3 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      const promise4 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      const promise5 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      const promise6 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      const promise7 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      const promise8 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      const promise9 = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      await Promise.all([
        promise1,
        promise2,
        promise3,
        promise4,
        promise5,
        promise6,
        promise7,
        promise8,
        promise9,
      ]).then(data => {
        console.log('End: ', new Date)
      })
    }
```

I am confused because this code below resolving in 4000ms, that means they starting simultaneously and resolving after ending of biggest timeout - 4000. This time Promises not resolving in chain

```
    async asyncData () {
      function startTimer (time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            resolve()
          }, time)
        })
      }

      console.time('Timer')
      Promise.all([
        startTimer(1000),
        startTimer(4000),
        startTimer(2000),
      ]).then(function () {
        console.timeEnd('Timer')
      })
    }
```

P.S. Sorry for bad English ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Javascript is synchronous and single threaded.

Comment: @DrewReese but what for async functions and promises needed? I just dont get it. I also tried to use/understand worker_threads and still can't find a solution

Comment: Browsers have a limit of the number of simultaneous connections they'll make to the same server, typically about 4.

Comment: check the browser developer tools network tab and watch what actually happens

Comment: @KitAliev they allow what is otherwise synchronous single-threaded code to run asynchronously, i.e. non-blocking on the main JS thread. Note that Promise.all resolves when *all* promises in the array resolve, but there is no guarantee to the order in which they are processed or resolved. In your first example 10x network requests that each resolve in ~200ms equals the 2 seconds as there seems to be outside interaction with the browser/network as others pointed out while in the second are timers set immediately, the longest, 4s, will dominate when the Promise.all resolves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem is that large numbers of simultaneous network requests, especially those made to the same endpoint, often take longer to resolve than if only one request was made - *even if you made all those requests in parallel*. Here's a screenshot from Chrome devtools of the requests:

[image]

As you can see, all the requests *are* being fired off immediately, but the subsequent ones are taking longer to resolve. Often this is caused by the endpoint (here, `jsonplaceholder`) throttling requests.

If you were making requests to your *own* server, and both your server and the script source had sufficient bandwidth, connectivity, and no throttling, the parallel requests would resolve at least close to the same time.

(Browsers may restrict the total number of connections allowed at any one time, as may OSs)

Comment: In other cases, if your server really is the bottleneck - by buying a more capable server, I think. But here, the bottleneck looks to be on jsonplaceholder, rather than on your server's network ability. If you wanted a quicker response, you could try making half of the requests via a separate script that makes the request from a different external IP, or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My requests running on server [NodeJS | Express] how can i increase the total number?

Comment: See above comment

Comment: (1) The bottleneck isn't your server, it's the endpoint you're connecting to (2) Even if the bottleneck *was* your server, the upgrade would probably involve the network connectivity settings with the provider, and not the physical machine specs